# Как вывести __VA_ARGS__ не зная их типа в макросе на C

Tags: c, строки, макросы

как вывести через fprintf() значения аргументов макроса __VA_ARGS__ не зная их типа

```
#define LOG(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] %s [%d]: %s /*__VA_ARGS__?*/\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, M)
```

Comment: Добавьте в макрос еще один fprintf для печати  `__VA_ARGS__`

Comment: На С++ не хотите перейти? Там такое элементарно делается.

Comment: Я же правильно понял, что вы хотите так: `LOG("a = ", a, ", b = ", b)`? Не так? `LOG("a = %d, b = %d", a, b)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартное решение. Типы есть, они спрятаны строке-шаблоне:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG(...)                                              \
    do {                                                      \
        fprintf(stderr, "INFO %s:%d: ", __FILE__, __LINE__);  \
        fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);                         \
        fputc('\n', stderr);                                  \
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LOG("start");
    LOG("argc = %d, argv = %p", argc, (void *)argv);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion var-args.c
>
> $ ./a.out 
> INFO var-args.c:13: start
> INFO var-args.c:14: argc = 1, argv = 0x7fff8c0e1a88
> ```

**P.S.** Компилятор проверяет соответствие шаблона и аргументов. Если убрать приведение из `(void *)argv`, то будет ошибка с диагностикой:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion var-args.c
> var-args.c: In function ‘main’:
> var-args.c:14:9: error: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char **’ [-Werror=format=]
>    14 |     LOG("argc = %d, argv = %p", argc, argv);
>       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        ~~~~
>       |                                       |
>       |                                       char **
> var-args.c:8:25: note: in definition of macro ‘LOG’
>     8 |         fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);                         \
>       |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
> var-args.c:14:29: note: format string is defined here
>    14 |     LOG("argc = %d, argv = %p", argc, argv);
>       |                            ~^
>       |                             |
>       |                             void *
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно печатать значения, не зная их типы. В C11 появился [`generic selection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic). С помощью него компилятор выбирает функцию по типу аргумента. В C нет перегрузки функций, а `generic selection` позволяет её имитировать.

Макрос `DUMP` печатает значение любого из трёх типов: `int`, `char *` и `const char *`. Можно добавлять ещё типы, я ограничился тремя для примера.

Макросы `DUMP1` - `DUMP9` раскрываются в цепочку вызовов `DUMP`. Каждый макрос обрабатывает аргументы согласно его номеру. Например: `DUMP4(1, 2, 3, 4)` раскроется в `DUMP(1); DUMP(2); DUMP(3); DUMP(4);`

Макрос `DUMPX` выбирает один из номерных макросов и применяет его к своим аргументам. Например `DUMPX(1, 2, 3, 4)` раскроется в `DUMP(1); DUMP(2); DUMP(3); DUMP(4);`.

Макрос `LOG` выводит от одного до девяти аргументов.

Это полностью стандартный код для C11. Если вы решитесь его использовать, рекомендую ко всем макросам, кроме `LOG`, добавить префиксы, чтобы уменьшить шанс пересечения с другими библиотеками. Например: `LOG_IMPL_DUMP`, `LOG_IMPL_DUMP1` - `LOG_IMPL_DUMP9`, `LOG_IMPL_DUMPX`, `LOG_IMPL_TENTH`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dump_int(int v) { fprintf(stderr, " %d", v); }
void dump_pchar(const char *v) { fprintf(stderr, " %s", v); }

#define DUMP(X)                   \
    _Generic(                     \
        (X)                     , \
        int         : dump_int  , \
              char *: dump_pchar, \
        const char *: dump_pchar  \
    )(X)

#define TENTH(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, ...) _10

#define DUMP1(V1) DUMP(V1);
#define DUMP2(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP3(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP4(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP5(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP6(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP5(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP7(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP6(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP8(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP7(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP9(V1, ...) DUMP1(V1) DUMP8(__VA_ARGS__)

#define DUMPX(...) \
    TENTH(__VA_ARGS__, DUMP9, DUMP8, DUMP7, DUMP6, DUMP5, DUMP4, DUMP3, DUMP2, DUMP1, _)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOG(...)                                             \
    do {                                                     \
        fprintf(stderr, "INFO %s:%d:", __FILE__, __LINE__);  \
        DUMPX(__VA_ARGS__)                                   \
        fputc('\n', stderr);                                 \
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LOG("start");
    LOG("argc =", argc, "argv[0] =", argv[0]);
    LOG(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion var-args.c
>
> $ ./a.out 
> INFO var-args.c:39: start
> INFO var-args.c:40: argc = 1 argv[0] = ./a.out
> INFO var-args.c:41: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

**P.S.** Думается мне, что можно с помощью аналогичных средств собрать формат по типам аргументов и построить один вызов функции `fprintf`. Сейчас их много, будет один.

**P.S.** Макрос `DUMP` можно доработать так, чтобы он печатал и имя параметра `LOG` и его значение. Меньше кода писать для отладки. Например: `LOG(argc, argv[0]);` напечатает `argc = 1 argv[0] = ./a.out`.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное проще всего в соответствии с описанием [Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) написать и использовать подобный макрос
следующим образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define LOG(M, FMT...) ({                                               \
      int l = fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] %s [%d]: %s ",                    \
                      __FILE__, __LINE__, M);                           \
      if (l > 0) {                                                      \
        l += fprintf(stderr, FMT);                                      \
        fputc('\n', stderr);                                            \
        ++l;                                                            \
      }                                                                 \
      l; })


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{

  LOG("Start", " ");
  LOG("Args:", "ac = %d av = %p", ac, av);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc t1.c && ./a.out 1 2 3
[INFO] t1.c [20]: Start  
[INFO] t1.c [21]: Args: ac = 4 av = 0x7ffc2f503168
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Comment: Вы воспользовались расширением из GCC. То же самое можно записать переносимо, через `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: А зачем так сложно? `fprintf( "[INFO] %s [%d]:" M, __FILE__, __LINE__,##__VA_ARGS__ )` и все.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это всё же хак. Печать в два вызова полностью стандартная, не требует штук вроде `##__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: `({ ... })` - нестандартное расширение GCC.

Comment: Я смотрю в C23 подвезли `__VA_OPT__`. Можно полностью стандартно вместо `,##__VA_ARGS__` сделать `__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, можно так: `LOG(M, ...)` ... `fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)`. Стандарт, не требует свежей версии.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Угу, а префикс тогда отдельным вызовом.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, что-то мой `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` как-то не понимает `__VA_ARGS__`

Comment: @avp, посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562482/416121

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ага, ваш вариант работает (значит  просто я что-то накосячил с `__VA_ARGS__` в своих тестах макросов)

Comment: За это время я нашел способ печатать значения совсем без типов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562495/416121. Сижу, горжусь потихоньку.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, уже увидел.  Я тоже вами горжусь, толком запомнить эту фичу С11 (чтобы писать не залезая в инет) так и не смог -)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал не просто `LOG(M,...)`, а `LOG(FMT,...)`, где `FMT` задаёт форматирование вывода.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG(FMT, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] %s [%d]: " FMT "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ __VA_OPT__(, ) __VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LOG("Start");
    LOG("Args: argc == %d, argv == %p", argc, argv);
    // Компилятор сообщит об ошибке: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument ... in expansion of macro ‘LOG’
    // LOG("Mismatch: argc == %d, argv == %p");
}
```

Результат:

```
[INFO] some.c [8]: Start
[INFO] some.c [9]: Args: argc == 1, argv == 0x7ffc2cc8f148
```

Comment: У меня в `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` это вообще не компилируется, ругается на `__VA_OPT__`  / (хотя мысль переделать макрос на формат `#define LOG(FMT, ...)` (т.е. заставить пользователя вставлять текст сообщения (`M` у автора вопроса) вполне здравая. Просто надо сделать 2 fprintf-а в макросе. Один печатает `__FILE__, __LINE__`, а другой само сообщение)

Comment: @avp да, это сравнительно свежая штука, поддерживается начиная с GCC 8

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю смысла использовать стандартные функции подмножества printf() совместно с макросом _Generic(). Это как купить билет на самолёт, и отправиться в путь пешком.
Вот готовое printo("text", double, float, uint(8-16-32-64)_t, int(8-16-32-64)_t )
https://github.com/AVI-crak/Rtos_cortex/tree/master/printo

Comment: `Вот готовое printo`. Ну.... тысячи строк вашего кода не смотрел.... Просто глянул реализацию первой приглянувшейся функции — `i32_char`. Сразу с ходу бросается в глаза UB из-за знакового целочисленного переполнения в этой строке `if (mi) value = 0 - value;` при `value == INT32_MIN`. Не очень обнадёживающее начало.

Comment: if (mi) value = (uint32_t) 0 - value;   https://godbolt.org/z/ozs8eqzMb

Comment: А теперь прикиньте, что будет делать с вашим творением *обычный программист* на поддержке, если понадобиться быстренько поправить формат лога?

Comment: "быстренько поправить формат лога?" - даже не знаю. Я полностью вырезаю лог после отладки модуля. Если обработка ошибок требует печати - модуль ещё не готов.